# Laravel : Handle findOrFail( ) on Fail

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am looking for something which can be like findOrDo(). Like do this when data not found. Something could be like

```
Model::findOrDo($id,function(){
   return "Data not found";
});
```

Is there any similar thing in laravel that I can do this elegantly and beautifully ?

*I tried googling but could not find one

Comment: What are you wanting to do if a model is not found?

Comment: @MartinBean at present I want to redirect. But then later i think it should be really useful for me at least. With out first have to query and then check if exists

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

// Will return a ModelNotFoundException if no user with that id
try
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
}
// catch(Exception $e) catch any exception
catch(ModelNotFoundException $e)
{
    dd(get_class_methods($e)); // lists all available methods for exception object
    dd($e);
}
```

Comment: This is the proper way to do it as outlined in the documentation `The findOrFail and firstOrFail methods will retrieve the first result of the query. However, if no result is found, a Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException will be thrown` http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Comment: Don't forget your semi colons boys and girls. The above example should have semi colons after each `dd()`

Answer (score 10):

Another option is to modify the default Laravel Exception Handler, found in app/Exceptions/Handler.php on the `render()` function I made this change:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if(get_class($e) == "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException") {
        return (new Response('Model not found', 400));
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

That way instead of getting a 500, I send back a 400 with a custom message without having to do a try catch on every single `findOrFail()`

Comment: I think this is the best way to handle the `findOrFail` exception. It's a single catch and if you want to still have a custom way of handling it, you can just add it to the function where the said method is called.

It helps debug easier as well since it's on a single place instead of all over the controllers.

Answer (score 5):

By default, when you use an Eloquent model’s `findOrFail` in a Laravel 5 application and it fails, it returns the following error:

```
ModelNotFoundException in Builder.php line 129:
'No query results for model [App\Model]'.
```

So to catch the exception and display a custom 404 page with your error message like "Ooops"....

Open up the `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file, and add the code shown below to the top of the render function:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
   if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException) 
   {
      abort(404, 'Oops...Not found!');
   }

   return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Source: https://selftaughtcoders.com/from-idea-to-launch/lesson-16/laravel-5-findorfail-modelnotfoundexception-show-404-error-page/

Answer (score 3):

An alternative process could be to evaluate a collection instead. So,

```
$modelCollection = Model::where('id', $id)->get();
if(!$modelCollection->isEmpty()) {
    doActions();
}
```

I agree it isn't as elegant, a one-liner or as case specific as you or I might like, but aside from writing a try catch statement every time, it's a nice alternative.

Answer (score 1):

as of Laravel v5.7, you can do this (the [retrieving single model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) variation of [@thewizardguy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51771603/2445763) answer)

```
// $model will be null if not found
$model = Model::where('id', $id)->first();

if($model) {
    doActions();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A little later for the party, [from laravel 5.4 onward, Eloquent Builder supports macros](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/CHANGELOG-5.4.md#added-24). So, I would write a macro (in a separate provider) like follows.

```
Builder::macro('firstOrElse', function($callback) {
   $res = $this->get();

   if($res->isEmpty()) {
       $callback->call($this);
   }

   return $res->first();
});
```

I can then do a retrieval as follows.

```
$firstMatchingStudent = DB::table('students')->where('name', $name)
    ->firstOrElse(function() use ($name) {
        throw new ModelNotFoundException("No student was found by the name $name");
    });
```

This will assign the first object of the result set if it is not empty, otherwise will adapt the behaviour I pass into the macro as a closure (throw `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException` in this case).

**For the case of a model also this would work, except that models always return the builder instance**.

Answer (score 1):

In the newer version of Laravel (for me in v9.41.0) we have the Register method in Handler.php ,
so for customize the exception of findOrFail method we have to add this code to that file:

```
$this->renderable(function (NotFoundHttpException $exception, $request) {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            //when you need it for API
            return response()->json([
                'responseCode'=> 404,
                'message' => "Item not found",
                'errorCode' => 1000404
            ], 404 );
        }else{
            return view("some-custom-view");
        }

    });
```

I needed **NotFoundHttpException** which has the namespace below (you can use any other Exception for customization) and have to be used out of the class:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
```