# customize ExceptionHandler in findOrFail error message

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Good morning all,

Laravel v7.+

I made a

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);
```

on my controller, it works well but when I have no result it sends me to a 404 page. 
I would like to be able to do a return back with error message. 
Some are talking about try catch. 
Do you have any other solution to optimize?

Thank you, good day, stay home!

Comment: See @Pitchinnate [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32989034/laravel-handle-findorfail-on-fail) it might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having this issue in a single Controller only, you can use `try` `catch`

If you need a more general solution, you can work with the exception render method (https://laravel.com/docs/master/errors#render-method) on the `ModelNotFoundException`

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        return response()->view('errors.custom', [], 404);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to try/catch

```
$user = User::find($id);
if(!$user){
    return redirect()->back()->with(['error' => 'Error message']);
}

... your other logic here
```